# Generating a good training dataset for decision tree building

Tags: machine-learning, cart

I am building a decision tree predicting the accuracy score of an image processing algorithm, based on a number of image parameters. I have identified 6 uncorrelated parameters that impact the accuracy of the method, and would like to include them all in the model.
In designing the training dataset for the model, I have the following questions:

1. Is there an accepted way of estimating the size needed for the training dataset, rather than just increasing its size until the prediction accuracy is the one desired?
2. Should the training dataset be:

   - Uniformly cover the ranges of variation of the different predictors,
   - Include more cases corresponding to challenging scenarios (extreme predictor values leading to extreme accuracy scores for example)
   - Represent the type of data that will be encountered in real life (when the model is used). This would lead to a rather normal distribution of predictor values within their range of variation.

This is all done in Matlab with the Statistics toolbox.

I hope my questions make sense. Any help, or links to relevant books or publications would be much appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance.

Beatrice

Comment: It sounds like you have the ability to generate new datapoints on demand? If so, you could use a Gaussian-process-type model to figure out which new sets of parameters would yield the most information. I've seen similar techniques applied for [hyperparameter optimization in machine learning](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.2944.pdf). (Sorry, I know this doesn't answer your immediate question.)

Comment: In terms of practical suggestions, I'd think that you should try to draw from the same distribution as real life. Otherwise the decision tree may implicitly learn a different (and incorrect) "baseline prediction." But I don't know too much about this area.